# The plot function in R version 3.2.4 Revised is not working

Tags: r, plot

The `plot` function in R version 3.2.4 Revised is not working, as the example below.

```
> i <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

> plot(i)
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Error in .External2(C_X11, d$display, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize,  : 
  unable to start device X11cairo
In addition: Warning message:
In (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :
  unable to open connection to X11 display ''
```

Can anyone help me what I can do to solve this problem?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: did you install [xquartz](http://www.xquartz.org)? also see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31283/error-in-r-unable-to-open-connection-to-x11) if that doesn't work

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: This work for Ubuntu @rawr ???

Comment: I'm with Ubuntu, @RichardTelford

Comment: Doubt it. what does `capabilities()[c('X11', 'cairo')]` return for you?

Comment: @rawr It returns 'TRUE' and 'TRUE'. I appreciate your help. I just closed the terminal and opened it again and it started to work. It's a mystery...

Comment: @DaniDepi sorry these are all shots in the dark since I am not at a ubuntu machine to test. what does `Sys.getenv('DISPLAY')` return and if you run `Sys.setenv('DISPLAY' = ':0.0')` then plot does it work?